# How do I make a form on my site ssl

Tags: php, ssl

Ok so the problem I have is this There is ssl on the server and I have a lease.php file that i need to be ssl...its posting to itself...any ideas what it is i need to do to activate it on this php file

Comment: Set the form action to "https: //your/uri"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if some one redirect to your  lease.php you should check if it is under ssl via:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTPS']!="on"){
header("Location: https://..../lease.php");die();
}
```

also you have to make sure that under lease.php every external resource like js,img,iframe and more has to be https as well, or you break it